# how to find out which index of element is selected in dropdown flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm new in flutter i try to make an `dropdownbutton` ,and i wanna when user clicked on a item,**send the index of that element to** `API`
and here is my dropdown

```
  DropdownButton<String> androidDropdown() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropdownItems = [];
    final List<String> dropDownItemsdata = [
      'inprogress',
      'packing',
      'sent'
    ];
    for (String currency in dropDownItemsdata) {
      dropdownItems.add(
        DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(currency),
          value: currency,
        ),
      );
    }

    return DropdownButton<String>(
      items: dropdownItems,
      hint: Text(
        'change status',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontFamily: font),
      ),
      onChanged: (value) {

        print(value);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation thoroughly: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Make a variable `var _selected = null`, this is the selected option in the dropdown menu.

**2.** Set the value of the `DropDownButton` to the `_selected`.

```
value: _selected,
```

**3.** Assume we have a function called `sendToAPI`, change the `onChanged` of the `DropDownButton` to this:

```
onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _selected = value;
        });
        sendToAPI(value); // or sendToAPI(dropDownItemsdata.indexOf(value));
      },
```

As shown in the comment, you can use `sendToAPI(dropDownItemsdata.indexOf(value))` to send the index of the selected option to the API.

**Full code:**

```
  var _selected = null;

  DropdownButton<String> androidDropdown() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropdownItems = [];
    final List<String> dropDownItemsdata = [
      'inprogress',
      'packing',
      'sent'
    ];
    for (String currency in dropDownItemsdata) {
      dropdownItems.add(
        DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(currency),
          value: currency,
        ),
      );
    }

    return DropdownButton<String>(
      items: dropdownItems,
      value: _selected,
      hint: Text(
        'change status',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontFamily: font),
      ),
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _selected = value;
        });
        sendToAPI(value); // or sendToAPI(dropDownItemsdata.indexOf(value));
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          String slectedValue = "Select Any Letter"  

          Container( 
                 child:    DropdownButton<String>(
                  isExpanded: true,
                  items: ["A","B","C"].map((String value) {
                    return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: new Text(value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {slectedValue = value;});
                    },
                  hint: Text(
                    slectedValue,
                    style: TextStyle(),
            ),),);
```